# Ansible lineinfile - modify a line

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm new to Ansible and trying to modify a line in `/etc/default/grub` to enable auditing.

I need to add `audit=1` within the quotes somewhere on a line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 rhgb quiet net.ifnames=0"
```

So far I've managed to delete the line and am only left with

```
net.ifnames=0, audit=1
```

when I use something like

```
lineinfile:
  state: present
  dest: /etc/default/grub
  backrefs: yes
  regexp: "net.ifnames=0"
  line: "\1 audit=1"
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may try this:

```
- lineinfile:
    state: present
    dest: /etc/default/grub
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=(?!.* audit)\"[^\"]+)(\".*)'
    line: '\1 audit=1\2'
```

This will add `audit=1` (with a leading space) just before closing double quote. It will not match without double quotes.
And it tries to be idempotent: doesn't match lines that already have `audit` (with a leading space) after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`.

I'd recommend to use sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions first (there's also a substitution mode there).
When you're satisfied with the result, proceed with the Ansible task.

Comment: @Jeff Bilbro - if you need to only add it to lines that have "net.ifnames=0" you'll need to add that to the regexp line that Konstantin Survorov provided.   Probably something like this:
    `regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*net.iframes=0.*(?!.*audit)\"[^\"]+)(\".*)'`

Comment: To make this also work when GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX is empty you can use `^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=(?!.*audit)\"[^\"]*)(\".*)`

Comment: For anyone else landing here with a somewhat related question: On Ubuntu 18.04 I wanted to use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` instead of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` because that seems to be the one used normally (where all the other parameters are).

Comment: Can anyone explain why does this permit any characters after the second double quote? Doesn't a proper line start and end with double quotes (or not have any double quotes on the line at all)?

Comment: could this line be added to a separate file in `/etc/default/grub.d/` dir and have the same effect?

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to make sure the parameter is also set to the correct value, so I used this replace invocation:

```yaml
replace:
  path: /etc/default/grub
  regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=(?:(?![" ]{{ option | regex_escape }}=).)*"?)\s*(?:{{ option | regex_escape }}=\S+\s*)?(.*")$'
  replace: '\1 {{ option }}={{ value }}\2'
vars:
  option: audit
  value: 1
```

This works if the option wasn't present previously, if it was but had the wrong option (only changes the value then) and if the whole string was empty (but adds a space before the option then). Also, it uses `regex_escape` to correctly work with option names that contain dots and the likes, and you only have to specify them once.

Comment: Very, very nice!

Comment: There is one problem with the regexp: if the option is position as the first after the quote, for example: ```GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="elevator=noop"``` then your regex will chew up the initial quote and resulting line ends without he first quote and it breaks grub.

This is the fix:

```regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="(?:(?!{{ option | regex_escape }}=).)*)([ ]{{ option | regex_escape }}=\w+[ ])?[ ]?(?:{{ option | regex_escape }}=\S+)?(.*\")$'``` and finally ```replace: '\1{{ option }}={{ value }}\3'```

Comment: You are right, fixed that (although in another way, since your answer probably matches partial options, like `ata.elevator` or something like that)